# How to make transaction number ordinal?

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means, one-hot-encoding

I wish to use k-means or hierarchical clustering on a dataset containing bank transactions.

```py
header_list = ["date", "recipient", "amount", "sender"]
df = pd.read_csv('data_for_applicants.txt', sep='\t', engine='python', names = header_list, parse_dates=[0])
```

```py
df['transaction'] = df['recipient'].astype(str) + df['sender'].astype(str)
df.drop(columns=['recipient', 'sender'], inplace=True)

df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)
```

```py
df.dtypes
```

```
amount          int64
transaction    object
month           int64
day             int64
dtype: object
```

```py
df.shape
```

```
(427632, 4)
```

```py
df.transaction.nunique()
```

```
130649
```

As you can see, the column `transaction` is categorical. Hence, I should either one-hot encode or do ordinal encoding.

1. If I one-hot encode it, that would generate `130649` new columns
   each having `427632` rows. That would probably break both k-means
   and hierarchical clustering. I have just 8GB of RAM on my laptop.
2. If I make it ordinal (using `pandas.to_numeric()`) then the
   clustering algorithms would yield bad results, because they would
   misjudge the distance (closeness) between transaction numbers.
3. I might use `OrdinalEncoder()`, but I am not sure if it would even
   have any benefit over simple `pandas.to_numeric()` above.

The question is then how to deal best with the categorical variable `df.transaction` before applying k-means or hierarchical clustering.